# Wifi is disabled and Network applet's "Enable Wfi" is not clickable

Tags: wireless, network-manager, rfkill

Every time in Network settings, Airplane mode switches on itself.

On running `nmcli nm` in terminal:

```
RUNNING : running          
STATE : connected           
WIFI-HARDWARE : disabled   
WIFI : disabled          
WWAN-HARDWARE : enabled  
WWAN : enabled
```

I don't know how to enable WIFI-HARDWARE and WIFI.
Also using "sudo rfkill unblock wifi" is not working.

I also checked the output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN   
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Hard blocked: yes

refers to the fact that there is a physical key combination or other button disabling your wifi.

In my case I had to click [Fn] + [F11]

and on my other laptop there is a toggle button on the left side I had to slide.

Comment: yes..it was fn+f2 in my case. Thanks..it worked..!!